# Can you call a specific params.value from ag-grid into your HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ag-grid

I'm new to ag-grid and web development in general, so I have this column definition where I have my image URL and using cellRenderer to display them as image.

Now I wanted to use these images on my main HTML file and was wondering if there is a way I can call specific parameter values (URL image links in order) from ag-grid into my HTML? I imagine calling them by index or something.

Hope my question makes sense, Thanks,

Comment: can you elaborate a little on this?

Comment: In the example code below (ag-grid tutorial), Is there a way for me to return the row data into my HTML file? Like Is it possible to extract the values "Toyota", "Ford" or "Celica" back into an HTML file? 

`const columnDefs = [
  { field: "make" },
  { field: "model" },
  { field: "price" }
];

// specify the data
const rowData = [
  { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
  { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
  { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
];`

Thanks

Comment: assuming that you are working with vanilla JavaScript implementation and have access to gridOptions, you can use  `gridOptions.api.rowModel.forEachNode(callback)` to iterate over each node in the grid and can access the data on that node.